# If discrete random variable $X$ take certain values, then calculate pdf of $Y=(X-2)^2$, mean and dispersion.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

So if discrete random variable $X$ takes values: $-2, 1, 2, 3, 6$, then I have to find density function $f(y)$ for a variable $Y=(X-2)^2$. Each of these variables have a probability of $0.2$. So for $X$ the $F(x)$ is 
$$F(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{5}, & \text{ if } -2\leqslant x<1 \\ \frac{2}{5}, & \text{ if } 1\leqslant x<2 \\ \frac{3}{5}, & \text{ if } 2\leqslant x<3 \\ \frac{4}{5}, & \text{ if } 3\leqslant x<6 \\ {1}, & \text{ if } x\geqslant 6. \end{cases}$$ But I don't know how to get density function for $Y$, neither how to find mean and dispersion. Can someone help?

Comment: If $X=-2$ then $Y=(-2-2)^2=16$. If $X=1$ then $Y=(1-2)^2=1$ and so on. There does not exist density function since distribution of $Y$ is discrete. You can find probability mass function and then calculate mean and variance.

Comment: You've defined the distribution function incorrectly. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\mathbb P(Y=k) = \mathbb P((X-2)^2=k) = \begin{cases}
\frac15,& k=0\\
\frac25,& k=1\\
\frac25,& k=16.
\end{cases}
$$
It follows that
$$
\mathbb E[Y] = \sum_k k\cdot\mathbb P(Y=k) = 0\cdot\frac15+1\cdot\frac25+16\cdot\frac25 = \frac{34}5,
$$
$$
\mathbb E[Y^2] = \sum_k k^2\cdot\mathbb P(Y=k) = 0^2\cdot \frac15 + 1^2\cdot\frac25 + 16^2\cdot\frac 25 = \frac{514}5,
$$
and hence
$$
\operatorname{Var}(Y) = \mathbb E[Y^2] - \mathbb E[Y]^2 = \frac{514}5 - \left(\frac{34}5\right)^2 = \frac{1414}{25}.
$$

Comment: Ok, as I understand you cut the amount of values that the variable takes, but why there is only probability of $\frac{2}{5}$ for $k=16$? Shouldn't the probability be $\frac{3}{5}$ for $k\le 16$? Or am I confusing with some other function?

Comment: $$\mathbb P(Y=16) = \mathbb P((X-2)^2=16) = \mathbb P(X=-2) + \mathbb P(X=6) = \frac 25.$$